# ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC or Silverlight or a mixture?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I want to start to implement a new web application (with many user interactions) from the scratch. I have 2 years experiences with ASP.NET. Now Microsoft offers ASP.NET MVC. I have read a little about the concepts behind, but I am not sure if I should use the classic ASP.NET variant or the new one. Perhaps it makes sense to mix it ? Or should I move to Silverlight ? What do you thing ? What are the advantages and disadvantages of all these variants ? Can ASP.NET MVC seen as the successor of ASP.NET or will both variants available in the future ?

Comment: Without knowing what your application is going to do it's going to be almost impossible to make a recommendation. The different technologies and methodologies have different strengths and weaknesses, but with no reference there's no way of knowing which are relevant.

Comment: And there are already plenty of questions on here dealing with the differences between those three technologies, anything we write here is just repeating them.

Comment: @slugster, bad thing asp:Repeater doesn't cover this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Silverlight used for RIA's or game development while classic ASP.NET and MVC are used for web applications. If you are familiar with classic ASP.NET better stick to it as MVC will bring you new level of complexity as any new way of development on other hand if you want a challenge which can in some rare cases bring your creativity to the top, go for MVC. I say that because some ppl report that they are far more productive in new to them technologies/languages rather than old ones. Especially if both are based on .NET so you will probably know most of the framework parts you need. MVC is just different way of development application when Silverlight is technology for different type of applications

Comment: MVC and its variants can be (and should be) used in Silverlight, so the OP is better off learning the pattern(s) now, regardless of the complexity. That 'complexity' should be embraced, it leads to better design, maintainability and testability than what you can achieve with classic ASP.NET.

Comment: All those "benefits" first of are subjective (except testability which makes you learn another framework , test unit one)... Second of all if you disagree with my words please next time do not make empty claims without proof. I haven't found yet any proof of MVC being able to lead you to better design or maintainability. Unit Testing was just another thing to learn while complex unit testing that used for complex web applications cannot be learned in one day and simple web applications does not require unit testing at all.

Answer (score -2):

Web application can be developed in two ways either Silverlight or ASP.NET MVC Framework.
Silverlight is Client Side and ASP.NET MVC is server side technology.If your application is focusing on UI, then you should be used Silverlight because Silverlight gives good UI inetrafec to Web Application and you can use Silverlight with Entity Frmaework.